# Key error django - passing additional stuffs with django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have my models like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(default='default.jpg')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Page(Group):
    name = models.IntegerField()
```

in my forms.py, to create a form for posting multiple images, I created this: I also override get_form_kwargs for passing the 'page' thing with the form as you can see that the Photo model has a page foreignkey.

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PhotoForm, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['page'] = Page.objects.get(pk=self.GET['pk'])
        return kwargs

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )
```

In my main urls.py, I say like:

```
path('page/<int:pk>/photos/', include('photos.urls'))
```

and in photos apps urls.py, I say:

```
path('progress-bar-upload/', views.ProgressBarUploadView.as_view(), name='progress_bar_upload')
```

and in my photos apps views.py I say:

```
class ProgressBarUploadView(View):

    model = Photo 

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        page = get_object_or_404(Page, page=self.kwargs['page'])
        return render(self.request, 'photos/progress_bar_upload/index.html', {'photos': photos_list, 'page':page})

    def post(self, request):
        time.sleep(1)  
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Then when in my html I call the page,

```
{{page}}
```

Then when I go to 'localhost:/page/1/photos/progress-bar-upload/' I get this error:

```
KeyError at /page/7/photos/progress-bar-upload/
'page'
```

So what can I do? Can someone help me? Any help will be much much appreciated.

Comment: Your view,, `progress_bar_upload` expects a keyword argument named `page`. But you are not passing it to the view

Comment: I don't fully understand, I have no function named ```progress_bar_upload``` in views.py. Where should I pass keyword argument named ```page```? Can you please kindly clarify?

Comment: It is the name of `ProgressBarUploadView` class